# Transfer compressed directory /file to workgroup system

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I want to transfer a file / directory  to any pc in the workgroup using java program, Is it possible using java to transfer a file/ directory to any other workgroup pc, a p2p file transfer possible using sockets,but i need to implement  in a way that any  pc could transfer to any pc in the workgroup

Comment: You copy any files/directories the UNC path where you want to copy the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The reason your questions aren't getting answered is that they're too vague and don't show your efforts to date. Try to take some time over asking your question, explaining what you've already looked at, explaining *fully* what you're trying to do, and you'll probably find that people actually do start helping you.

Comment: also, we would need to know your operating system to know which kind of "workgroup" you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do that. You first have to write a client-server program in Java to negotiate under which ip-address other clients can be found (for your p2p). So, the server keeps a list of say client-names and their ip-addresses and clients look up other clients by connecting to the server. Then the server-connection is disconnected and the client can connect to another client; for this to work there has to run a ServerSocket on every client which will accept incoming connections. Then you can use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to read and write files on the respective endpoints.

Here is more information:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html
>   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html